# Identifying the file system of an img file and mount it

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, disk-image, embedded-system

I have downloaded an SD image loader from [nxp website](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/evaluation-and-development-boards/i.mx-evaluation-and-development-boards/android-os-for-i.mx-applications-processors:IMXANDROID?tab=Design_Tools_Tab).
The name of the downloaded item is `O8.1.0_1.4.0_ANDROID_TOOL_7ULP_GA` (This is not an Android question btw).

The image loaded on my SD is inside the zipped file under the name of

```
recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

I would like to modify this image before I load SD with this file.
What software should I use to open this image? I cannot identify the filesystem.

This `.img` file could be a raw image. But, still I have no idea how to mount it.

---

Here are my tries.

**mount**

```
sudo mount -t auto recovery-imx7ulp.img ./img -o loop
```

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

```
dmesg | tail
```

```
[  124.816635] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens33: link is not ready
[  124.828615] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens33: link is not ready
[  124.829592] e1000: ens33 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  124.831624] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ens33: link becomes ready
[  141.529441] NET: Registered protocol family 40
```

**fdisk**

```
fdisk -lu recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
Disk recovery-imx7ulp.img: 32 MiB, 33554432 bytes, 65536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**file**

```
file recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
recovery-imx7ulp.img:
     Android bootimg,
     kernel (0x62808000),
     ramdisk (0x63800000),
     second stage (0x63700000),
     page size: 2048,
     cmdline (console=ttyLP0,115200 init=/init androidboot.console=ttyLP0 con)
```

**parted**

```
sudo parted recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /home/ar/tmp/recovery-imx7ulp.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) u                                                                
Unit?  [compact]? B                                                       
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /home/ar/tmp/recovery-imx7ulp.img: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)                                                            
Disk /home/ar/tmp/recovery-imx7ulp.img: 33554432B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
(parted) ^C
```

**losetup**

```
losetup -P recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
losetup: recovery-imx7ulp.img: failed to use device: Success
```

```
sudo losetup --offset 115200 /dev/loop2 recovery-imx7ulp.img
sudo fsck -fv /dev/loop2
```

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/loop2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop2
```

**blkid**

```
blkid -o value -s TYPE recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
(empty output)
```

**disktype**

```
sudo disktype  recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
--- recovery-imx7ulp.img
Regular file, size 32 MiB (33554432 bytes)
```

**Head of the file in hex**

```
hexdump -C recovery-imx7ulp.img | head -40
```

```
00000000  41 4e 44 52 4f 49 44 21  08 f1 8e 00 00 80 80 62  |ANDROID!.......b|
00000010  00 17 55 00 00 00 80 63  b4 54 00 00 00 00 70 63  |..U....c.T....pc|
00000020  00 01 80 62 00 08 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...b............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  63 6f 6e 73 6f 6c 65 3d  74 74 79 4c 50 30 2c 31  |console=ttyLP0,1|
00000050  31 35 32 30 30 20 69 6e  69 74 3d 2f 69 6e 69 74  |15200 init=/init|
00000060  20 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64  62 6f 6f 74 2e 63 6f 6e  | androidboot.con|
00000070  73 6f 6c 65 3d 74 74 79  4c 50 30 20 63 6f 6e 73  |sole=ttyLP0 cons|
00000080  6f 6c 65 62 6c 61 6e 6b  3d 30 20 61 6e 64 72 6f  |oleblank=0 andro|
00000090  69 64 62 6f 6f 74 2e 68  61 72 64 77 61 72 65 3d  |idboot.hardware=|
000000a0  66 72 65 65 73 63 61 6c  65 20 76 6d 61 6c 6c 6f  |freescale vmallo|
000000b0  63 3d 31 32 38 4d 20 63  6d 61 3d 34 34 38 4d 20  |c=128M cma=448M |
000000c0  62 75 69 6c 64 76 61 72  69 61 6e 74 3d 75 73 65  |buildvariant=use|
000000d0  72 64 65 62 75 67 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |rdebug..........|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000240  c4 ab 31 08 3f 94 04 fb  09 88 86 e6 d6 c2 af 99  |..1.?...........|
00000250  d4 5e ac b7 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.^..............|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000800  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  |................|
*
00000820  03 00 00 ea 18 28 6f 01  00 00 00 00 08 f1 8e 00  |.....(o.........|
00000830  01 02 03 04 00 90 0f e1  20 05 00 eb 01 70 a0 e1  |........ ....p..|
00000840  02 80 a0 e1 00 20 0f e1  03 00 12 e3 01 00 00 1a  |..... ..........|
00000850  17 00 a0 e3 56 34 12 ef  00 00 0f e1 1a 00 20 e2  |....V4........ .|
00000860  1f 00 10 e3 1f 00 c0 e3  d3 00 80 e3 04 00 00 1a  |................|
00000870  01 0c 80 e3 0c e0 8f e2  00 f0 6f e1 0e f3 2e e1  |..........o.....|
00000880  6e 00 60 e1 00 f0 21 e1  09 f0 6f e1 00 00 00 00  |n.`...!...o.....|
00000890  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000008a0  0f 40 a0 e1 3e 43 04 e2  02 49 84 e2 0f 00 a0 e1  |.@..>C...I......|
000008b0  04 00 50 e1 ac 01 9f 35  0f 00 80 30 00 00 54 31  |..P....5...0..T1|
000008c0  01 40 84 33 6d 00 00 2b  5e 0f 8f e2 4e 1c 90 e8  |.@.3m..+^...N...|
000008d0  1c d0 90 e5 01 00 40 e0  00 60 86 e0 00 a0 8a e0  |......@..`......|
000008e0  00 90 da e5 01 e0 da e5  0e 94 89 e1 02 e0 da e5  |................|
000008f0  03 a0 da e5 0e 98 89 e1  0a 9c 89 e1 00 d0 8d e0  |................|
00000900  01 a8 8d e2 00 50 a0 e3  01 a9 8a e2 0a 00 54 e1  |.....P........T.|
00000910  1e 00 00 2a 09 a0 84 e0  70 90 8f e2 09 00 5a e1  |...*....p.....Z.|
00000920  1a 00 00 9a 09 ac 8a e2  ff a0 ca e3 6c 50 4f e2  |............lPO.|
00000930  1f 50 c5 e3 00 00 4f e1  1f 00 00 e2 1a 00 50 e3  |.P....O.......P.|
```

---

Also no luck with

```
sudo kpartx -av recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter recovery-imx7ulp.img
```

**gparted**

```
sudo gparted imx7ulp_m4_demo.img
```

```
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
/home/tmp/recovery-imx7ulp.img: unrecognised disk label
```

[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQY2F.png)

**simg2img**

```
simg2img imx7ulp_m4_demo.img out.img
```

```
Invalid sparse file format at header magi
Failed to read sparse file
```

Comment: The output of file says its an Android bootimg.

AFAIK, you can't mount a boot image directly as it's not a filesystem. It does have a ramdisk, which perhaps could be mounted using an android-specific boot image tool. 

What modifications are you hoping to make?

Comment: have you tried mount -t sysfs -o loop ... ?

Comment: Many thanks, @ServeLaurijssen - for a different Android bootimg I had, `sudo mount -t sysfs -o loop nandc.img /tmp/test` worked great; one can then see folders (block bus class dev devices firmware fs hypervisor kernel module power) in the image.. I just wonder, how can one `fsck` such an image?